# Changing python3 to python2.7 as the default python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

currently, my default python version is 3.8, but my company want me to use python2.7. So, I need to change the default version of python to 2.7. But when I was searching about changing default version of python, most of the results were about change from python2.7 to python3. Is there anyone know how to change the version of python from 3.8 to 2.7?
For more information: when I run `which python`, it returns`/Users/taesankim/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`
And when I run `which python2.7`, it returns `/usr/bin/python2.7`

Please let me know if I missed something or I need to add more information.

Thank you.

Comment: python 2 is no longer supported, you're company needs to upgrade ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/python2.7` with

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Then confirm `which` now refers to new link.

You might have to start a new console before confirming with `which`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but when I run that command, it shows me: ```ln: /usr/bin/python: Operation not permitted``` did I do something wrong?\

Comment: Oh, you likely need `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python` in order to give correct permission to generate file. (and enter credentials as needed) If `/usr/bin/python` already exists, then this won't work.